# Creating stream of elements from collection

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, junit5, mongodb-asyc-driver

I am using Junit 5 Dynamic tests. 
My intention is to create a stream of elements from the collection to pass it on to test in JUnit5. 
However with this code, I am able to run only 1000 records. How do I make this work seamlessly non-blocking.

```
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mydatabase.getCollection("mycoll");
    final List<Document> cache = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Document>());

    FindIterable<Document> f = collection.find().batchSize(1000);
    f.batchCursor(new SingleResultCallback<AsyncBatchCursor<Document>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(AsyncBatchCursor<Document> t, Throwable thrwbl) {
            t.next(new SingleResultCallback<List<Document>>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(List<Document> t, Throwable thrwbl) {
                    if (thrwbl != null) {
                        th.set(thrwbl);
                    }
                    cache.addAll(t);
                    latch.countDown();;

                }
            });
        }
    });
    latch.await();
    return cache.stream().map(batch->process(batch));
```

**Updated Code**

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("setUp")
void cacheTest(MyClazz myclass) throws Exception {
    assertTrue(doTest(myclass));
}
public static MongoClient getMongoClient() {
 // get client here
}

private static Stream<MyClazz> setUp() throws Exception {
    MongoDatabase mydatabase = getMongoClient().getDatabase("test");
    List<Throwable> failures = new ArrayList<>();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    List<MyClazz> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
            mydatabase.getCollection("testcollection").find()
            .toObservable().subscribe(
            document -> {
                list.add(process(document));
            },
            throwable -> {
                failures.add(throwable);
            },
            () -> {
                latch.countDown();
            });
    latch.await();
    return list.stream();
}

public boolean doTest(MyClazz myclass) { 
// processing goes here
}
public MyClazz process(Document doc) { 
// doc gets converted to MyClazz
   return MyClazz;
}
```

Even now, I see that all the data is loaded after which the unit testing happens. 
I think this is because of latch.await(). However, if I remove that, there is a chance that no test cases are run as the db could possibly be loading collection.

My use case is : I have million records in mongo and am running sort of integration test case with them. It wouldn't be feasible to load all of them in memory and hence I am attempting the streaming solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I fully understand your use case but given that your question is tagged with `java` and `mongo-asyc-driver` this requirement is certainly achievable:

> create a stream of elements from the collection to pass it on to test ... make this work seamlessly non-blocking

The following code:

- Uses the MongoDB RxJava driver to query a collection
- Creates a Rx `Observable` from that collection
- Subscribes to that `Observable`
- Records exceptions
- Marks completion

  ```
  CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  List<Throwable> failures = new ArrayList<>();
  collection.find()
          .toObservable().subscribe(
          // on next, this is invoked for each document returned by your find call
          document -> {
              // presumably you'll want to do something here to meet this requirement: "pass it on to test in JUnit5" 
              System.out.println(document);
          },
          /// on error
          throwable -> {
              failures.add(throwable);
          },
          // on completion
          () -> {
              latch.countDown();
          });
  // await the completion event
  latch.await();
  ```

Notes:

- This requires use of the [MongoDB RxJava driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-rx/) (i.e. classes in the `com.mongodb.rx.client` namespace ... the `org.mongodb::mongodb-driver-rx` Maven artifact)
- In your question you are invoking `collection.find().batchSize()` which clearly indicates that you are not *currently* using the Rx driver (since `batchSize` cannot be a Rx friendly concept :)
- The above code is verified with v1.4.0 of the MongoDB RxJava driver and v1.1.10 of `io.reactive::rxjava`

**Update 1**: based on the change to your question (which follows my original answer), you have asked: *" I see that all the data is loaded after which the unit testing happens. I think this is because of latch.await()"*? I think you are pop[ulating a list from the observable stream and *only after the observable is exhausted* do you start invoking `doTest()`. This approach involves (1) streaming results from MongoDB; (2) storing those results in-memory; (3) running `doTest()` for each stored result. If you really want to stream all-the-way then you should call `doTest()` from within your observable's subscription. For example:

```
mydatabase.getCollection("testcollection").find()
        .toObservable().subscribe(
        document -> {
            doTest(process(document));
        },
        throwable -> {
            failures.add(throwable);
        },
        () -> {
            latch.countDown();
        });
latch.await();
```

The above code will invoke `doTest()` as it receives each document from MongoDB and when the entire observable is exhausted the latch will be decremented and your code will complete.

Comment: Thanks this is good. But I don't think I can call doTest right away as these are dynamic tests.I need to be able to create a stream of mongo db results and return them. Is there a way I can do it ? I am okay if there is a different solution for my use case. The hardest part seems to be batching the dynamic tests. I am sure there is a way, just that I don't know.

Comment: Sounds like there might be some confusion here. The code in my answer **does** "create a stream of mongo db results". If you then choose to batch them before returning batches of them then you are no longer streaming. Or to put it another way; if the code in my answer does not serve your purposes then you don't actually want a stream of MongoDB results.

Comment: I agree that the code you provided does create the stream of mongo results. It just wouldn't work with the kind of junit I was writing and the kind of use case. I was wondering if there is a solution to my usecase and hence  was thinking about batching